# Handle properties that are null from AJAX request

Tags: json, ajax

Sending an AJAX request with data from an HTML form, the request returns a JSON array with objects. Sometimes some of the object properties have a value of null, null gets printed on the page, is there a good way to handle this directly in the success callback before printing it on the page?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ajaxCall").click(function () {

            let carBrand = $('#carBrand').val();
            let carModel = $('#carModel').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/API/AjaxCall',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    carBrand: carBrand,
                    carModel: carModel
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        let el = $('#print');
                        el.append('<tr><td>' + data[i].carBrand + '</td><td>' + data[i].carModel+ '</td></tr>');
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I know there are frameworks that handle this in the HTML tags etc, but looking for a way to handle it in the success callback specifically.

Comment: Do you want to skip the row if `carBrand` or `carModel` is null?

Comment: Just want the field to be empty instead of displaying null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display an empty field instead of null use [jQuery $.trim](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) (unexpectedly converts null and undefined to empty string):

```
let el = $('#print');
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    el.append('<tr><td>' + $.trim(data[i].carBrand) + '</td><td>' + $.trim(data[i].carModel) + '</td></tr>');
}
```